# Combined two MySQL query into one

Tags: mysql, select

I have two different queries as follows-

```
SELECT s.serialno, s.productid, s.description, s.in_quantity, s.uom, 
s.shiptype,s.receiveddate, s.project_id, IF(EXISTS(SELECT so.serialno 
FROM stockout so WHERE so.serialno = s.serialno),1,0) AS movementHistory
FROM stockin s WHERE s.productid = 'UKL40114/11HP'
```

sample result of above query with limit 0,5

```
mysql> SELECT s.serialno, s.productid, s.description, s.in_quantity, s.uom,
    ->     s.shiptype,s.receiveddate, s.project_id, IF(EXISTS(SELECT so.serialno

    ->     FROM stockout so WHERE so.serialno = s.serialno),1,0) AS movementHist
ory
    ->     FROM stockin s WHERE s.productid = 'UKL40114/11HP' LIMIT 0, 5;
+------------+---------------+--------------------------+-------------+------+--
--------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+
| serialno   | productid     | description              | in_quantity | uom  | s
hiptype | receiveddate        | project_id | movementHistory |
+------------+---------------+--------------------------+-------------+------+--
--------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+
| A23001YKG5 | UKL40114/11HP | RADIO UNIT/RAU2 13/11 HP | 1           |    4 |
      3 | 2008-08-27 00:00:00 |          1 |               1 |
| A230024FUV | UKL40114/11HP | RADIO UNIT/RAU2 13/11 HP | 1           |    4 |
      2 | 2008-11-17 00:00:00 |          1 |               1 |
| A230024NHT | UKL40114/11HP | RADIO UNIT/RAU2 13/11 HP | 1           |    4 |
      2 | 2009-03-17 00:00:00 |          1 |               1 |
| A230024KQT | UKL40114/11HP | RADIO UNIT/RAU2 13/11 HP | 1           |    4 |
      2 | 2009-03-17 00:00:00 |          1 |               1 |
| A230024UR4 | UKL40114/11HP | RADIO UNIT/RAU2 13/11 HP | 1           |    4 |
      2 | 2009-03-17 00:00:00 |          1 |               1 |
+------------+---------------+--------------------------+-------------+------+--
--------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

and

```
SELECT so.out_quantity, so.serialno, so.siteid, so.employee_id, 
so.deliverytime, so.receivername 
FROM stockout so WHERE so.serialno = 'A23001RK3N'
```

sample result of above query-

```
mysql> SELECT so.out_quantity, so.serialno, so.siteid, so.employee_id, so.delive
rytime, so.receivername                           FROM stockout so WHERE so.seri
alno = 'TU8D322820';
+--------------+------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---
-----------+
| out_quantity | serialno   | siteid    | employee_id | deliverytime        | re
ceivername |
+--------------+------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---
-----------+
| 1            | TU8D322820 | 001BDS011 |          38 | 2008-06-26 10:25:00 | 0
           |
+--------------+------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---
-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If `movementHistory == 1`, I am executing second query in on PHP page. But, I would like to do this query inline with the first query. 
I am thinking like following query-

```
SELECT s.serialno, s.productid, s.description, s.in_quantity, s.uom, s.shiptype, 
s.receiveddate, s.project_id, IF(EXISTS(SELECT so.serialno FROM stockout so WHERE
so.serialno = s.serialno),1,0) AS movementHistory
CASE movementHistory
WHEN '1' THEN (SELECT so.out_quantity, so.serialno, so.siteid, so.employee_id,
so.deliverytime, so.receivername 
FROM stockout so WHERE so.serialno = 'TU8D322820')
WHEN '0' THEN 0
END AS Policy
FROM stockin s WHERE s.productid = 'UKL40114/11HP'
```

How may I achieve?

Comment: please, provide an example of your db tables here -> www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: okay, I am giving and example.

Comment: sorry, I unable to fiddle sql to sqlfiddle.com, Can I share sample data here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly you can try this:

```
SELECT 
    s.serialno, 
    s.productid, 
    s.description, 
    s.in_quantity, 
    s.uom, 
    s.shiptype,
    s.receiveddate, 
    s.project_id, 
    IF(EXISTS(
            SELECT 
                so.serialno 
            FROM 
                stockout so 
            WHERE 
                so.serialno = s.serialno
        ),
        1,
        0
    ) AS movementHistory,
    so.out_quantity, 
    so.serialno, 
    so.siteid, 
    so.employee_id, 
    so.deliverytime, 
    so.receivername 
FROM 
    stockin s
LEFT JOIN  stockout so
    ON so.serialno = 'A23001RK3N'
    AND IF(EXISTS(
                SELECT 
                    so1.serialno 
                FROM 
                    stockout so1 
                WHERE 
                    so1.serialno = s.serialno
            ),
            1,
            0
        ) = 1   
WHERE 
    s.productid = 'UKL40114/11HP'
```

Comment: movementHistory detecting as unknown column

Comment: i have updated my query... also can you post the tables structures ?

Answer (score 1):

Try [JOINING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) the two tables using `LEFT JOIN`. Check this query:

```
SELECT SI.serialno
    , SI.productid
    , SI.description
    , SI.in_quantity
    , SI.uom
    , SI.shiptype
    , SI.receiveddate
    , SI.project_id
    , IFNULL(SO.out_quantity, -1) AS out_quantity
    , IFNULL(SO.siteid, '') AS siteid
    , IFNULL(SO.employee_id, -1) AS employee_id
    , IFNULL(SO.deliverytime, '') AS deliverytime
    , IFNULL(SO.receivername, -1) AS receivername
    FROM stockin SI
    LEFT JOIN stockout SO ON SO.serialno = SI.serialno
    WHERE SI.productid = 'UKL40114/11HP'
    LIMIT 0, 5;
```

You can change the values returned from `stockout` table if they are `NULL`. Check [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function.

Comment: +1 but i do not know if he wants to join by `serialno` since in the queries `serialno` are different

Comment: I followed the query for the `movementHistory` which is `stockin.serialno = stockout.serialno`. That's just a hunch though :D Thanks!

Comment: You both did awesome ! Both query meet mine requirements but, I also need the movementHistory as 1 or 0 for further work. So, I am going with @Stephan